# SSIS Foreach loop, send email if no file is present?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple SSIS package that grabs 1 or more flat files and imports the data into a SQL Server 2012 table, then a separate package archives the file..  The packages work perfectly, but I want it to warn me if there is no file present when it starts.

I know that the Foreach loop generates a warning when there are no files:

`Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.`

I have not been able to find a way to use that warning to trigger an email, as it does not cause the package to fail, and I am not sure if there is a constraint or expression that can trigger a next step based on a warning.

I use the for each loop to populate a variable `@[User::FileName]` with any filename matching the pattern which is preset.

A notify operator task with the expression `@[User::FileName]==""` and completion or success fires no matter what, if there is a file or not.

Is this possible in SSIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle warnings by implementing the `OnWarning` event handler.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I used a notify operator task.